# Is person who dies because of Covid-19 will be shaheed one in afterlife?

Tags: hadith

Many of them are dying because of covid19 pandemic. Is these persons will be shaheed one in afterlife

Comment: Such a thing can not be claimed categorically. However the disease has similarities to those mentioned as martyrdom in ahadith so it can be hoped that it will also count as martyrdom.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific report for that but it is hoped that it like the other diseases like plague which has the status if martyrdom.

Answer (score -1):

Sahih Bukhari, Hadith 2830
"It is martyrdom for every Muslim to die for a epidemic"

So, I can say, Yes. You can hope so. All you need to make your Iman stronger.

Comment: طاعون is plague, not epidemic.

Comment: you may say that way but translations says different. from sahih hadith of Tirmizi and other sahih hadith of Bukhari, the description given indicates epidemic

Comment: Which translation are you relying on? The one published by [Darussalam](https://archive.org/stream/SahihAlBukhariArabic-EnglishTranslation/SahihAl-bukhariVol.4-Ahadith2738-3648#page/n69/mode/2up).

Comment: i rely on the bengali translation

Answer (score -1):

AOA wrwb

Remember these ppl in ur prayers,  now they r with Allah, and Allah knows the best how to deal with them

yes we have a hint in this hadith, so we can make dua from Allah to bless them with the reward of a martyred person

but everything is by the will of Allah, we cant guarantee ourselves how can we guarantee some one else and his fate

may Allah give us all hidayat and make us among the blessed believers. ameen